# Como colocar scroll em collapse do Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de colocar o efeito de scroll suave ao clicar no "veja mais" do collapse no código abaixo. Estou usando HTML, CSS, jQuery e Bootstrap.

HTML:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Portfólio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>
   <div class="container title-h1">
        <h1>Portfólio</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Carrousel ---------------------------------------------------------->


    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="row carousel">   
          <div class="portfolio container col-lg-3">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                 <h5>Nome Projeto</h5>
                 <div class="card-img-top"></div>
                 <a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> 
                     <div class="card-body">
                      Veja mais
                     </div>
                 </a>
              </div>   
          </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 500px"></div>
    <div class="container collapse row" id="collapseExample">
            <div class="container col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="ladoEsquerdo">

                <h2 class="title-h2">Titulo</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin pulvinar et urna vitae porta. Integer venenatis nisi in nisi congue lobortis. Proin fermentum ut tortor eget facilisis. In nec felis vulputate, suscipit nisl non, blandit tellus. Nullam eget tortor urna. In dignissim lectus non dolor sodales molestie. Duis in vulputate augue, sed tristique sem. Donec commodo ex a elit tempor laoreet. Quisque tortor libero, lobortis id metus eu, dignissim efficitur nunc. Suspendisse eu lorem at urna volutpat sagittis. </p>


                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">ACESSE O SITE</a><br>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">CONHEÇA A HISTÓRIA</a>

            </div>
            <div class="container col-lg-8" id="ladoDireito">
                <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-6" style="height:200px; background-color:white;"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="height:200px; background-color:gray; margin-left: 0px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2px">
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:200px; background-color:blue; margin-right: px;"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:200px; background-color:white; margin-right: px;"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:200px; background-color:blue; margin-right: px;"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2px">
                    <div style="width:100%;height:200px; background-color:gray; margin-right: px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>



    </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Eu editei a pergunta, pois tinha colocado as informações de forma errada. Gostaria de fazer o scroll da página quando o usuário clicasse no "Veja mais". Eu tentei fazer mas quando eu clicava pra fechar o collapse que abria, a tela descia novamente bugando a tela.

Comment: Dá uma olhada no Scrollspy do Bootstrap pra ver se te ajuda. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Comment: Cara está meio confuso seu código da para explicar um pouco melhor o efeito, nem scroll tem na página...

Comment: Não é exatamente isso que eu queria. O problema não é colocar scroll na página o problema é o scroll com o collapse.

Comment: @hugocsl eu editei a pergunta, acredito que agora dê pra ver certinho.

Comment: Vc quer descer a tela ao clicar no "veja mais"?

Comment: Sim, exatamente. Mas somente quando o "modal" debaixo não estiver aberto. 

Quando você clica no "veja mais" a primeira vez ele abre uma caixa embaixo e quando clica pela segunda vez a caixa debaixo fecha novamente e some. Gostaria que quando clicasse no "veja mais" pra abrir o "modal" quando abrisse, a tela fizesse um scroll suave até o "modal".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só usar o callback do evento `shown.bs.collapse` ([veja doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events)) e rolar a tela com `animate` até a div que foi aberta:

```js
$(function(){
   $('#collapseExample').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      $('html').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top})
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container title-h1">
        <h1>Portfólio</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Carrousel ---------------------------------------------------------->


    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="row carousel">   
          <div class="portfolio container col-lg-3">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                 <h5>Nome Projeto</h5>
                 <div class="card-img-top"></div>
                 <a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> 
                     <div class="card-body">
                      Veja mais
                     </div>
                 </a>
              </div>   
          </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 500px"></div>
    <div class="container collapse row" id="collapseExample">
            <div class="container col-lg-4 col-md-4" id="ladoEsquerdo">

                <h2 class="title-h2">Titulo</h2>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin pulvinar et urna vitae porta. Integer venenatis nisi in nisi congue lobortis. Proin fermentum ut tortor eget facilisis. In nec felis vulputate, suscipit nisl non, blandit tellus. Nullam eget tortor urna. In dignissim lectus non dolor sodales molestie. Duis in vulputate augue, sed tristique sem. Donec commodo ex a elit tempor laoreet. Quisque tortor libero, lobortis id metus eu, dignissim efficitur nunc. Suspendisse eu lorem at urna volutpat sagittis. </p>


                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">ACESSE O SITE</a><br>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">CONHEÇA A HISTÓRIA</a>

            </div>
            <div class="container col-lg-8" id="ladoDireito">
                <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-6" style="height:200px; background-color:white;"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6" style="height:200px; background-color:gray; margin-left: 0px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2px">
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:200px; background-color:blue; margin-right: px;"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:200px; background-color:white; margin-right: px;"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="height:200px; background-color:blue; margin-right: px;"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2px">
                    <div style="width:100%;height:200px; background-color:gray; margin-right: px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>



    </footer>
```

Comment: Opa, cara. Era justamente isso que eu queria. Eu consigo mudar até onde o scroll desce na página? No projeto que tô desenvolvendo eu tenho um menu fixo, e quando o a página desce uma parte do "modal" que abre é coberto com o menu

Comment: Sim. Vc ajusta a posição subtraindo um valor. Por exemplo, afastar 50 pixels do topo: `$("#"+id).offset().top-50`